# didSelectRowAtIndexPath to performSegueWithIdentifier gose wrong but didDeselectRowAtIndexPath is ok?

Tags: ios, tableview, segue

I have a tableView that the cell have segue to a detailed view controller.

When I use **didSelectRowAtIndexPath** to perform the detail view controller, I can not dismiss the view controller correctly.

```
   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, **didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath**: NSIndexPath) {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("addressCell", sender: tableView)
}
```

After use

```
 dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

The detailed view dose not dismissed and have warning:

```
AddAddressViewController: 0x7f891b929d20> on 
<AccountAddress: 0x7f89195e3ba0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

But when i use **didDeselectRowAtIndexPath**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, **didDeselectRowAtIndexPath** indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("addressCell", sender: tableView)
}
```

***It runs correctly and no warning!***

What is the problem?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have the segue linked to the cell selection action in your storyboard as well as performing the segue in didSelectrow?

Comment: you must check segue connection properly..it might be wrong

Comment: Yes i check the storyboard have "triggered segues" that connected to the detailed view controller and I will update a picture

Comment: Consider that `prepareForSegue` is called directly (passing the cell in the `sender` parameter) if the segue is connected to the table view cell and in this case overriding `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is not needed. What's the second segue for?

Comment: The second segue is for a button to "add new address" , first segue is to "selected cell and edit", i have override prepareForSegue

Comment: Yes I should not override the func didSelectRowAtIndexPath . It's ok only to connect segue and override prepareForSegue. Thx @vadian

Comment: In this case just don't override `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: Yes, thank you. You could answer this question and I will accept the answer :)